# Unable to open Instagram mobile version using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web

So, I am trying to create an automated bot to post on Instagram but I have not been able to open mobile version of Instagram using selenium.

I have tried using

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=200,700")
```

To set the size of my chrome window in selenium but It still opens the desktop version.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def site_login():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='//home/kartikey/Desktop/Files/Insta_Bot/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get ('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    time.sleep(3)
    # To login
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('EMAIL')
    passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    passwordInput.send_keys('*******')
    passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    # To turn on Notifications
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]').click() 
    return None
site_login()
```

I am able to access the desktop version but desktop version doesn't allow posting.

So, I want to know how can I use selenium so that I can open mobile version of Instagram ?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mobile-browser-emulator/lbofcampnkjmiomohpbaihdcbjhbfepf?hl=en) or [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3)?

Comment: Actually found the answer in `chromedriver ` by using            `mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Nexus 5" }  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)`

Comment: Post the same as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I resolved the above problem by using `Mobile Emulation` in `Chrome Options` which helped in emulating mobile version of `Instagram` and enabling the functionality of Posting through the web.

```
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Nexus 5" }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
```

Comment: Why don't you just set a mobile user agent to the browser?

Comment: `chrome` has provided this feature. So, I used it and will look into `user_agent`.